# When is it okay to compare C strings by char * equality?

Tags: c, string-literals

I know it doesn't make sense for two arbitrary c-strings (`const char *`) by comparing them `(a == b)`.

But I think that when both are defined by the SAME string literal, this is legal.

For example, here:

```
#include <stddef.h>

const char * const meals[] = {
    "none",
    "breakfast",
    "lunch",
    "dinner"
};

#define NO_MEALS  meals[0]
#define BREAKFAST meals[1]
#define LUNCH     meals[2]
#define DINNER    meals[3]

// i hours after midnight, hour_to_meals_map[floor(i)] is being served.
const char * hour_to_meal_map[] = {
    NO_MEALS,
    NO_MEALS,
    NO_MEALS,
    NO_MEALS,
    NO_MEALS,
    BREAKFAST, // i = 5
    BREAKFAST,
    BREAKFAST,
    BREAKFAST,
    BREAKFAST,
    BREAKFAST,
    LUNCH, // i = 11
    LUNCH,
    LUNCH,
    LUNCH,
    LUNCH,
    LUNCH,
    DINNER, // i = 17
    DINNER,
    DINNER,
    DINNER,
    DINNER,
    DINNER,
    DINNER // i = 23
};

// Returns a boolean for whether the two hours have the same meal being eaten.
int same_meal(size_t hour_one, size_t hour_two) {
    return hour_to_meal_map[hour_one] == hour_to_meal_map[hour_two];
}
```

(As for why you would make `hour_to_meal_map` map to strings rather than to indices is anyone's guess.. but I'm working on a project that is set up this way.)

Am I correct that this is legal here, and that what matters is that there is only one spot that each value is written as a literal? (`#define NO_MEALS "none"` was deliberately avoided!!)

If this code is in a header file, that doesn't make a difference, does it? (I expect the standard requires that `meals` have identical values in each compilation unit?).

I find lots of questions from beginners asking about cases where it's pretty clear they should be using `strcmp`, but I can't find one that answers this particular case. Any help would be appreciated, particularly if you can point me to the right part of the C standard so I can be *really* sure I understand all the subtleties.

Comment: in that case [`enum`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumeration-enum-c/) might be more useful.

Comment: Is there any issue you are having when implementing those? The C standard might as well be tested with actual code. You also get to test on your actual implementation instead of reading about what it should be.

Comment: No, haven't experienced any problems thus far. Just want to be sure I'm not abusing the C standard (and wanted to create a question where the answer wasn't "use strcmp!!" like all the others I found!). The actual code is extremely similar to this.

Comment: @dvhh I agree; my goal is basically to work within the structure of an already-written program if possible.

Comment: I don't think that initialisation is legal. Some gcc versions accept it, but I'm certain it's not portable; `meals[0]` is not a constant expression (in C) and a static initialiser must be all constants.

Comment: @rici damn... I work in C++ most of the time (only use C for legacy stuff) and wrote this up in gcc so I didn't know that! Might have to re-tool a bit. :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing two strings of the same type with `==` or `!=` is always legal.  This is detailed in section 6.5.9 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) which details Equality Operators:

> *2* One of the following shall hold:
>
> - both operands have arithmetic type;
> - both operands are pointers to qualified or unqualified versions of compatible types;
> - one operand is a pointer to an object type and the other is a pointer to a qualified or unqualified version of `void`;or
> - one operand is a pointer and the other is a null pointer constant.
>
> ...
>
> *4* **Two pointers compare equal** if and only if both are null pointers, **both are pointers to the same object (including a pointer to an object
>   and a subobject at its beginning) or function**, both are pointers to
>   one past the last element of the same array object, or one is a
>   pointer to one past the end of one array object and the other is a
>   pointer to the start of a different array  object  that  happens  to 
>   immediately  follow  the  first  array  object  in  the  address space

In this case you have an array of pointers, and you assign the value of one of those pointers into another array.  So if you compare two pointers and they both contain the value of (for example) `meals[0]`, e.g. the address of the string constant "none", they are guaranteed to compare equal.

What you have to watch out for is if a given string constant is used in multiple places.  In that case, they're not necessarily the same.

For example, given this:

```
const char *s1 = "test";
const char *s2 = "test";
```

The values of `s1` and `s2` are not guaranteed to be the same as the two strings constants can be distinct from each other, although compilers may choose to make them the same.  This differs from:

```
const char *s1 = "test";
const char *s2 = s1;
```

Where `s1` and `s2` **will** be the same, and this mirrors your case.

As you mentioned, it would make more sense for `hour_to_meal_map` to contain numeric constants (preferably members of an `enum`) and for those constants to subsequently map to an array of strings.  But the pointers to strings constants are effectively just that.

Comment: To make things worse, in the case of the two `"test"` literals, the compiler will likely use the optimization feature known as "string pooling", only actually storing one of them and thereby giving the same address to `s1` and `s2` both. If that's compliant with the C standard is another story, but that's how many optimizers work. Perhaps comparing the two addresses with each other will block that optimization, in which case the comparison is a bad thing for the sake of memory consumption.

Comment: @Lundin I already know the answer to that one. The compiler is permitted by the standard to do string pooling (or not). So `s1 == s2` can definitely return true or false. It's not undefined behavior though, so it's a "legal" comparison. Even though a "legal" comparison, I consider this a useless one, so I was hoping for my question to be about when it is okay to do this type of comparison **and expect it to be useful** (I'm not counting pre-checking as useful since it's more of a minor optimization).

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few cases where `char *` equality is meaningful:

1. the case you gave: by copying from the same pointer
2. for most (all?) compilers: with any same-value string literals in the same translation unit. This is an extremely common optimization, and can easily be tested anyway.
3. if you explicitly pass the string through an `intern()` function
4. as a quick short-circuit comparison before performing an expensive check of the value

Comment: what is "an `intern()` function" ?

Comment: @MM A function that returns a unique identity string with the given value. It's trivial to implement using any hashtable-like data structure.